# How to integrate Java DB shipped with JDK in to Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans-6.9

I am using Netbeans IDE 6.9.1 and jdk1.7.0_04 x64. I am not getting anything in Database node in Services tab of Netbeans?

How to integrate Java DB in Netbeans? Do I have to download any tools for Netbeans?

Comment: have you seen this: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer, I don't know but it was not working with Netbeans 6.9.1, I had re-installed that  but couldn't found. Then I installed latest Netbeans - 7.2.1, and I got it working. Netbeans 7.2.1 has Java DB integrated.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create New connection to your database.

In the Services tab, Right Click on Databases--> New Connection.

New Connection Wizard should open up. Choose Driver from combo box. Netbeans should reflect path to selected jdbc driver type. Click Next.

Provide JDBC connection URL parameters like Host, Username, Password and click on "Test Connection".

You should get "Connection Succeeded" message else check parameter values.

Click on Finish.

Comment: when I was right clicking Database, nothing was popping. No menu popped. But in Netbeans 7.2.1 I got Java DB node inside Database node.

Comment: when I was right clicking Database, nothing was popping. No menu popped. But in Netbeans 7.2.1 I got Java DB node inside Database node.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [NetBeans Docs & Support](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html), we need to have Net NetBeans 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3 or Java EE to work with JavaDB.